# Move all files within subfolders to parent folder

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, windows-explorer, cmd.exe

Firstly, I'm aware there are tons of similar questions, and I know because I must have tried adapting at least 5 of them, but I'm still here asking because my crappy grasp of CMD (which I actually thought I was getting good at up until this point) is frustrating me with generic, unhelpful errors, and I can't understand what part of the syntax is wrong. This is likely due to the fact that other questions deal with the folder/filename structures of their respective OPs, and when I try to adapt the code to my own folder/file structure it refuses to work. Therefore, I'm here asking for a CMD `for` loop solution that'll actually work for my own file and folder structure.

I have a parent folder which contains many other folders, in which there are files:

```
Parent Folder
     Subfolder
           File1
           File2
     Subfolder
           File1
           File2
     Subfolder
           File1
           File2
```

...and so on.

I'm wanting to use a CMD `for` loop in combination with the `move` command to extract all the files in the subfolders to the parent folder, leaving each subfolder empty.

When giving the CMD `for` loop please break down what each part of the command is doing, as this'll help make sure I understand the code and hopefully minimise the trouble I have getting it to work for myself.

Comment: what if you did `dir /s/b >a.a`  to get a list of all files, one per line. Then you `move ` at the beginning of each line, and `c:\blah\myparentfolder` at the end of each line then you have a list of command and can name the file blah.bat and run it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, I finally figured it out by adapting code from yet another question. Thanks to @AFH for clarifying the parts I was unsure about in the comments to this answer, and for his general help with it - it's much appreciated.

---

### To Extract All Files from Subfolders to their Parent Folder

`for /r "PARENTFOLDER" %d in (*.*) do move "%d" "PARENTFOLDER"`

Remember to replace all instances of `PARENTFOLDER` with the path to the folder that you want to extract the files to.

---

### To Extract All Files from Subfolders *and* Delete Empty Subfolders

It's unlikely you'll need to keep the empty subfolders left over after extracting the files from them - I certainly didn't - so the below command automates the deletion of them, too.

`for /r "PARENTFOLDER" %d in (*.*) do move "%d" "PARENTFOLDER" && cd "PARENTFOLDER" && for /f "delims=" %d in ('dir /s /b /ad ^| sort /r') do rd "%d"`

Once again, replace all instances of `PARENTFOLDER` with the path to the folder that you want to extract the files to.

By this point, however, it's no longer a one-liner, and starts to get a bit convoluted when pasted into the command line, so it's easier to just put the whole thing in a batch file. Using variables for the path to the parent folder allows you to replace just the one instance of `PARENTFOLDER` at the beginning of the file, and it's also the safer option, preventing against any accidental deletion of empty folders that you might want to keep.

---

### The Batch File

Paste into a text file, replace `PARENTFOLDER` with the path to the folder you want it to work with, and save it with the `.bat` extension. Run in any directory.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET parent="PARENTFOLDER"
CD /d %parent% 
FOR /r %parent% %%d IN (*.*) DO MOVE "%%d" %parent% 
FOR /f "delims=" %%d IN ('DIR /a:d /s /b ^| SORT /r') DO RD "%%d"
ECHO Done. Press any key to terminate script.
PAUSE >NUL
```

Comment: The `for` command syntax is not rational, but the first `%d` defines `d` as the loop variable, and the second `%d` is what the loop variable expands to on each pass of the loop (Unix syntax is more rational: `for ... d in ... do ...`). The first instance is not expanded, so it does not need quoting, unlike after the `do`, where `%d` may expand to file names with embedded blanks. There is nothing special about `d`: any single letter could be used, but `d` is logical for directories (or `f` for files). Even more irrationally, `%%d` must be used in a batch (`.cmd` or `.bat`) file.

Comment: Thanks for the acknowledgement that it's not rational, @AFH, I felt like it was just me that was missing something. One more thing - there are some files in the parent folder, and because of how the command above is written, it wastes time copying those files into the directory they're already in. There also appears to be some sort of bug that makes it hang there for a while. How would the command be modified to leave files in the parent directory alone, and only drill down into its sub-folders? Feel free to answer under this one or post as a separate answer.

Comment: Without testing, I think you want a nested `for`, along the lines of `for /d %d in (PARENTFOLDER\*) do for /r "%d" %f in (*.*) do move "%f" TARGETLOCATION`. If you include the extra requirements into your question, I'll submit an answer, for the benefit of others.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. What it does is run the nested `for` loop a set number of times. Testing on a parent folder with 7 subfolders and 3 files in it, I noticed that running it as above tends to result in 2 runs of the nested `for` command. When enclosing the first path in double quotes within the parentheses, it runs it 7 times - same as the amount of subfolders in the parent folder. On each occasion though, and no matter how many times they're run, none of those nested `for` loops work to acually extract files from subfolders; everything stays unchanged. Really odd.

Comment: If `PARENTFOLDER` contains blanks, it will need to be quoted. I suggest you put an `echo` between the first `do` and the second `for`, to check exactly what nested `for` command would be executed. Your conditions have so many possible variants that I can't set up a representative test here.

Comment: Okay, I'd always assumed that where there are parentheses, quotes wouldn't be needed, but that's clearly not the case, and it seems like that might be part of the problem judging from the output I'm getting by the echo - it's only interpreting parts of the directory names. I've included the quotes and this time the nested for loops runs a lot more time, but is still ineffective, so I'll get back to you as soon as I've figured out what exactly it's doing. It's also worth mentioning that both the PARENTFOLDER AND TARGETLOCATION in this case are the same places, for whatever that's worth.

Comment: If you don't quote `PARENTFOLDER` and it's something like `name with spaces`, the first `for` will evaluate as `for /d %d in (name with spaces\*) do ...`, so `d` will become successively `name`, `with`, then any files matching the mask `spaces\*`. Parentheses do not stop the requirement to quote. The only time you needn't quote is with the `cd` command, which takes the rest of the line as a single parameter, including any spaces (though `Tab` expansion inserts quotes); `md` and `rd` can act on multiple directories, so need quotes if the names have spaces.

Comment: I can't really make sense of the output from the CMD command, so I've pasted it here: http://pastebin.com/etrmhGu7.

Comment: The log looks like what I would expect. I simulated it here (without the `echo`) by creating directories and files, and it seemed to do what I understand you want.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. It worked fine in the end, looked like all I needed was a fresh eye on it. Must have been getting the paths confused. Anyway, I've updated the answer to make it clearer and more intuitive for anyone else. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I'm glad you have solved it.